# How do I prevent my Bootstrap Alert from blocking items in my Nav when shown?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

So this is my `_notices.html.erb`:

```
<% flash.each do |msg_type, message| %>
<div class="row pt-6 alert-messages">
  <div class="col-lg-6 offset-lg-3">
      <div id="inner-message" class="alert <%= bootstrap_class_for(msg_type) %>">
        <div class="container">
          <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span>×</span></button>
          <%= message %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This is the corresponding CSS:

```
#inner-message {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.alert-messages {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 7000;
}
```

However, once that alert is active and on the screen, all the elements behind that `.alert-messages` div is unclickable as can be seen in the screenshot below.

[image: alert blocks out nav elements behind it]

So how do I get my Bootstrap alert div to float above all of the elements currently on screen without pushing everything else down (which the `position: fixed` and other attributes of `.alert-messages` does) without it blocking out the elements covered by the full `.alert-messages` div and making them unclickable?

**Edit 1**

Per @symphonic's answer below, this is the result.

[image: result of symphonic answer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
<div class="row pt-6 alert-messages">
 <div class="col-lg-6 offset-lg-3">
  <div id="inner-message" class="alert <%= bootstrap_class_for(msg_type) %>">
   <div class="container">
    <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span>×</span></button>
     <%= message %>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

To this:

```
<div id="inner-message" class="alert-messages alert <%= bootstrap_class_for(msg_type) %>">
 <div class="container">
   <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span>×</span></button>
   <%= message %>
 </div>
</div>
```

And use this css:

```
.alert-messages {
 position: fixed;
 top: 20px;
 z-index: 7000;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Comment: This kinda works, in the sense that it no longer blocks the navigation, but the alert now looks weird. Refresh the question to see the result.

Comment: @marcamillion Updated answer

Comment: Perfect. Works like a charm. Thanks!